# What code will actually be generated when a generic struct implements `Deref`?

Tags: rust, dereference

I can't really understand the dereference here. The type of `foo` is `TattleTell<&str>`. The method `len()` is from `foo.value`, i.e. `foo.value.len()`. So why deref of TattleTell is invoked?

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;
struct TattleTell<T> {
    value: T,
}
impl<T> Deref for TattleTell<T> {
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        println!("{} was used!", std::any::type_name::<T>());
        &self.value
    }
}
fn main() {
    let foo = TattleTell {
        value: "secret message",
    };
    // dereference occurs here immediately
    // after foo is auto-referenced for the
    // function `len`
    println!("{}", foo.len());
}
```

Comment: `foo.value.len()` would access `.len()` without invoking `.deref()`, but since there's no `.len()` method on `foo` Rust tries inserting `.deref()`.

Comment: @eggyal Oops, I've mixed it up with Go's anonymous field, under the assumption that `foo` gets the methods of `foo.value`. XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't fully describe Rust's auto-dereferencing rules because they are covered in other answers. For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28552082/493729).

In your case, you are trying to call a method, `len`, on a `TattleTell<&'static str>`. This type doesn't directly have that method so, using the rules in that [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28552082/493729), Rust goes looking for it, using the following steps:

1. Check if the method exists on `&TattleTell<&'static str>`. It doesn't.
2. Check if the method exists on `*&TattleTell<&'static str>`. Due to your `Deref` implementation, this is a `&'static str`, so the method exists.

Comment: I'm new to Rust and not familiar with the jargons, so I don't know the exact keyword to search. Thanks for your time. :-)